# How do I AUTOMATICALLY hide side bar and panel when I minimize(reduced size) vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

**Problem:** The sidebar and panel hides a lot of available screen space when I minimized vscode. It's tedius to always press the shortcut keys just to hide em.

**What do you want?** To automatically hide the sidebar and panel when I minimize vscode.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzGzR.png)

Comment: You might be able to do this with a task. Let me see if its possible, give me a little bit of time.

Answer (score 1):

You may find this extention helpful: [marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sirmspencer.vscode-autohide).
And also, Ctrl + B will help you hide the side bar mannually

Answer (score 0):

you can use shortcut key <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd> to hide/show the side panel.